# Difference between 2 dates in minutes

Tags: python, datetime, time

can you tell me how can I calculate difference between 2 dates and get a result in minutes. 
For exmpl. : date1 - 2016/07/13, 14:25:00
             date2 - 2016/07/14, 10:00:00
If my format Is maybe different from format that python use(while I was searching for answer I saw a several formats) feel free to adapt it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you read the documentation for `datetime`? Is there something there you don't understand? This isn't on on-demand code-writing service.

Comment: I tried it but I cant make it works correctly and I wont post any part of code becose I don't want to my project idea be copied by someone. I hope that you understand me.

Comment: Why will someone copy the code related to comparing dates? If they do, it will be for their own good. We are not asking to share complete code :)

Comment: Post an *example* of what you've tried, not your entire business logic. If you can't bring yourself to post an example, then I would suggest you hire someone to write code for you, because again, this isn't a free code-writing service. It is a collaborative repository of common programming-related questions. Questions are suppose to be *useful to other people*. It isn't your own personal service.

Comment: Please read [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Moinuddin Quadri juanpa arrivillaga, you are both right about this.

Answer (score 0):

import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def date(dd,vd,dp,vp):

```
datetimeFormat = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'    
time1 = ('{0} {1}'.format(dd,vd))
time2 = ('{0} {1}'.format(dp,vp)) 
timedelta = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, datetimeFormat) - datetime.datetime.strptime(time1,datetimeFormat)
print (timedelta)
```

def main():

```
date1,time1='2016/07/13','14:25:00'
date2,time2='2016/07/14','10:00:00'
date(date1,time1,date2,time2)
```

if **name**=='**main**':
    main()

If you compile it you will get something like 19hrs which is incorrect. Also I need result in minutes.